# Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string

Tags: javascript, syntax, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Maybe the title is not clear enough, I just didn't know how to specify what I'm looking for and my English is really bad, sorry.

I'm trying to create function that returns object value, but also plays nice with nested objects. For example:

```
var obj = {
  foo: { bar: 'baz' }
};
```

I want to access the value of obj.foo.bar by suppling the string "foo.bar" to the function.

```
function(obj, path) {
  // Path can be "foo.bar", or just "foo".
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is now supported by lodash using _.get(obj, property). See https://lodash.com/docs#get

Comment: Since this question was marked as a Duplicate (even it's not) I have to answer in comment. You can use ECMAScript6 Destructuring: `var obj = {foo: { bar: 'baz' }};({foo:{bar:value}} = obj);console.log(value);`

Comment: If you want to properly handle any issue while retrieving the value, plus intelligent handling of functions, check out [path-value](https://github.com/vitaly-t/path-value) to help with that.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var obj = {
  foo: { bar: 'baz' }
};

function deepFind(obj, path) {
  var paths = path.split('.')
    , current = obj
    , i;

  for (i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
    if (current[paths[i]] == undefined) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      current = current[paths[i]];
    }
  }
  return current;
}

console.log(deepFind(obj, 'foo.bar'))
```

Comment: @7elephant and qiao: Fails (throws error) if any part of the path evaluates `null`. That could be a feature or a bug, depending on your viewpoint. :-)

Comment: how can you handle array inside object?

Comment: @mohammadpakivand i beleive you can simply use a number instead of a string: example: path = 'myprop.0' 
will access the first index of the array under 'myprop'

Answer (score 109):

This works correctly:

```
var deep_value = function(obj, path){
    for (var i=0, path=path.split('.'), len=path.length; i<len; i++){
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    };
    return obj;
};
```

Here is the proof / demo: [jsfiddle.net/tadeck/5Pt2q/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/tadeck/5Pt2q/13/)

EDIT: I have removed redundant variables, shortened the code.

Comment: beautiful. better than anything in the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: extended for array support. http://jsfiddle.net/5Pt2q/20/

Comment: @SteveBlack better how?  It supports a more restricted syntax, and has no error checking for attempting to resolve a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think it would be safer to check for `obj[path[i]] === undefined`

Comment: any idea how to do this the other way around? I have a nested object/property/key and want the path inside an object as a string.

Comment: @Sumit: This is trickier - you would need to know about recurrence and you would need a working way of comparing (eg. object `a` with object `b`, determining if they are equal). If this is not enough, I suggest writing another question, linking this answer, and listing what you have tried (the "recurrence" part and "comparing" parts should be two different functions).

Comment: @Tadeck I just looped through the whole object recursively and added the path to each property again. Talking about a JSON schema. Thanks for your input!

Comment: This is bad because it doesn't take into consideration `path.test[0].test`

Comment: It's bad practice to mutate arguments.

Comment: @Dimitry: Did you check if it works as you described? I did and it is not true that the argument is in any way mutated: http://jsfiddle.net/5Pt2q/242/

Comment: @Tadeck yes, it works without problems because arguments is a string, which passed into function as value. If it was object (or array), it will be passed as reference, so changing object argument triggers original object change too. So it's good practice to always not mutate arguments to eliminate possible problems.

Comment: @callback: Maybe 'path.test.0.test' can solve your problem.

Comment: same for ES6:  `const deep_value = (o, p) => p.split('.').reduce((a, v) => a[v], o);`

Comment: This fails for cases where the target path is null. See https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lake-srzrcs for a version that handles that case (including some tests).

Answer (score 18):

You mean something like this ? It is a recursive version

```
function recLookup(obj, path) {
    parts = path.split(".");
    if (parts.length==1){
        return obj[parts[0]];
    }
    return recLookup(obj[parts[0]], parts.slice(1).join("."));
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/kExSr/

Comment: GOLD! I was able to use this to map a path /Root[1]/This/worked to an object {"Root[1]":This{worked:"value"}}    . had to trim the leading / and change . to / but otherwise beautiful.

Comment: this doesn't look too fast. Shouldn't join() the paths again, just check if path is a string or an array

Answer (score 10):

something like:

```
function(obj, path) {
  var current=obj; 
  path.split('.').forEach(function(p){ current = current[p]; }); 
  return current;
}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118023/134069

Comment: Another way without mutation: `const lens = (obj, path) => path.split(".").reduce((o, key) => o && o[key] ? o[key] : null, obj);`

Comment: @YuriyGorbylov almost perfect, added a typeof to allow falsy values (`0` etc.): `(obj, path) => path.split(".").reduce((o, key) => o && typeof o[key] !== 'undefined' ? o[key] : undefined, obj)`

Answer (score 7):

You'd want to split the string on the dot and then repeatedly index into the object, e.g. along the lines of:

```
function goDeep(obj, path) {
    var parts = path.split('.'),
        rv,
        index;
    for (rv = obj, index = 0; rv && index < parts.length; ++index) {
        rv = rv[parts[index]];
    }
    return rv;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uwayom)

That works because you can access the property of an object in a couple of different ways: There's dotted syntax using a literal (`obj.foo`), and there's bracketed syntax using a string (`obj["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, it doesn't have to be a string literal. In in all of the, `rv` is set to the same value:

```
rv = obj.foo.bar;
// Or
rv = obj.foo["bar"];
// Or
f = "foo";
rv = obj[f].bar;
// Or
s = "b";
rv = obj.foo[s + "ar"];
```

Comment: Surely, the requirement was not expressed, but might we not suspect that OP might equally well want a function call such as `goDeep(myObj, 'bar[3].baz')`? That may be out of scope for the current question...

Comment: @DavidHedlund: Fair point, it may well be useful to check for the bracketed form within each `part` in order to be fully compatible with JavaScript's own syntax. I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP. :-)

Comment: (Well, not *fully*, as to do that you'd have to basically re-invent [or -shudder- use] `eval`. But say, mostly compatible with.)

Comment: Well granted, *mostly compatible* is probably preferable over *fully compatible* in this case :)