# JS checking deep object property existence

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to find an elegant way to check the if certain deep properties exist in an object. So practically trying to avoid monstrous protective checks for undefined eg.

```
if ((typeof error !== 'undefined') && 
  (typeof error.responseJSON !== 'undefined') &&
  (typeof error.responseJSON.error) && 
  (typeof error.responseJSON.error.message)) {
      errorMessage = error.responseJSON.error.message;
}
```

What I'm thinking about is a convenience-function like

```
if (exists(error.responseJSON.error.message)) { ... }
```

Any ideas? For convenience, the use of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)-library is ok for the solution.

Comment: You could do this by passing your request as a string to a function. The function should split the string by "." or something, then iterate over each segment looking for each value. There are other questions and good answers about this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string

Comment: I'm thinking if there's a way of handling this for an object, not as a string? Of course I could just JSON.stringify the object, but I'd feel a lot better if it'd handle the objects directly.

Comment: If you used an object you'd need to create the entire structure you're looking for (which is bulky and even worse than `&&` all over the place). A string may seem weird, but it's the most flexible and compact solution. An alternative is to pass an array, which is just the string pre-split. Then iterate over that drilling down into the target object.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several possiblities:

**Try-catch**

```
try {
  errorMessage = error.responseJSON.error.message;
} catch(e) { /* ignore the error */}
```

Fails for:

```
Object.defineProperty(error, 'responseJSON', {
  get: function() { throw new Error('This will not be shown')
});
```

**&&**

```
errorMessage = error && error.responseJSON && error.responseJSON.error && error.responseJSON.error.message;
```

Fails for:

```
error.responseJSON = 0;
// errorMessage === 0 instead of undefined
```

**function**

```
function getDeepProperty(obj,propstr) {
  var prop = propstr.split('.');
  for (var i=0; i<prop.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object')
      obj = obj[prop[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}

errorMessage = getDeepProperty(error, 'responseJSON.error.message');

// you could put it all in a string, if the object is defined in the window scope
```

Fails for:

```
// It's hard(er) to use
```

**function alternative** - see comment by @Olical

```
function getDeepProperty(obj) {
  for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object')
      obj = obj[arguments[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}

errorMessage = getDeepProperty(error, 'responseJSON', 'error', 'message');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this [underscore mixin](https://gist.github.com/megawac/6162481#file-underscore-lookup-js) to look up a variable with a path. It takes an object and string and t

```
_.mixin({
    lookup: function (obj, key) {
        var type = typeof key;
        if (type == 'string' || type == "number") 
            key = ("" + key).replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, function (m, key) { //handle case where [1] may occur
                return '.' + key.replace(/["']/g, ""); //strip quotes
            }).split('.');
        for (var i = 0, l = key.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (_.has(obj, key[i])) 
                obj = obj[key[i]];
            else 
                return undefined;
            }
        return obj;
    }
});
```

Now call in your example:

```
_.lookup(error, 'responseJSON.error.message') // returns responseJSON.error.message if it exists otherwise `undefined`
```