# Options to NOT use eval executing JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I want to see which options do I have to execute a string whichs looks for a value inside a JSON without using eval().

My JSON looks like this:

```
var caso = {
    "_id": "C1M3bqsB92i5SPDu",
    "type": "bpm",
    "bpm": {
        "_data": {
            "_id_bpm": "bpm_solicitud_viaticos"
        },
        "milestones": {
            "solicitud": {
                "toma_de_datos": {
                    "nombre": "RAUL MEDINA",
                    "clave": "123",
                    "departamento": "Finanzas",
                    "cantidad": "456"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'v a string with the value:

```
var step = "caso.bpm.milestones.solicitud.toma_de_datos.nombre";
```

I'm getting the value that I want from that JSON with this:

```
var thevalue = eval(step);
```

Which are my options instead of eval()? Both efficient and easy to implement?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: you can use: new Function;

Comment: Is it just a dot delimited string?

Comment: Try a get from path function see [Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string) or [What is the best to select a javascript object property at any depth?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39979/what-is-the-best-to-select-a-javascript-object-property-at-any-depth)

Comment: @Brad Your comment would actually be helpful if you posted a link explaining the difference. For all we know, the OP completely understands the difference and is simply showing an example of parsed JSON into an object literal that they are working with.

Comment: @Ian You're right... that's why I added my comment.  Either Laerion will know what I'm talking about and explain, or will show where the confusion is, so I can provide a targeted explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pieces = step.split('.'),
    result;

pieces.shift(); //discards superfluous "caso"
result = caso[pieces.shift()];

while (pieces.length >= 1) {
    result = result[pieces.shift()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is always in that format, you could split it and iterate over it

```
var pieces = step.split('.');
var parent = window;

while(parent && pieces.length) {
    parent = parent[pieces.shift()];
}

if(parent && pieces.length === 0) {
    // parent is now the value
}
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZjEt/

Comment: There may be no window scope; there also may be no this :(

Comment: I'd reasonably expect the OP to figure that out. SO is to help move people in the right direction, not hold their hand.