# How to use eval() to set value to a field provided as an argument

Tags: javascript

I'd like to do something like this:

```
function someFunction(expression){
    eval(expression) = 1234;
}
```

Or in other words, to pass a certain field name as an argument and then set a value to this field.
How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: I can't use bracket notations because I can't know which object the user is trying to set

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value to a new variable with a variable name, in the global scope, you can just do this:

```
function someFunction(expression){
    window[expression] = 1234;
}
```

There is really no good excuse to use `evil()`

Comment: You assume that the object is under "window". I want to provide a power user a way to write the whole object path as a string.

Comment: Then you'll want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string

Comment: That should do it, I just thought that there would be a shorter way. Thanks

Comment: @user3367818: sure, `eval` would be shorter, but it's _very_ dangerous. In case this answer or the comments helped you, please consider accepting it :-)