# Angular: Cannot retrieve function parameter value as an object property selector

Tags: function, angular, variables, filter, parameters

I have an issue trying to retrieve a function parameter value as an object property selector into a **.filter()** method.

This is my code:

```
myFunction(property, value) {
    function myFilter(obj) {
        return obj.details.name == value;
    }
    return this._http.get(this.Url).map((response: Response) => response.json().filter(myFilter));
}
```

I want to replace `return obj.details.name == value;` by `return obj.property == value;`.

*obj.**property*** is the parameter of my function *myFunction(property, value)*. The ***value*** parameter value works fine and is well retrieved.

This is what I want:

```
getFilteredFMsBy(property, value) {
    function specificFilter(obj) {
        return obj.property == value;
    }
    return this._http.get(this.Url).map((response: Response) => response.json().filter(specificFilter));
}
```

If I define the value of property in the function, same case. It doesn't work:

```
getFilteredFMsBy(property, value) {
    property = "details.name";
    function specificFilter(obj) {
        return obj.property == value;
    }
    return this._http.get(this.Url).map((response: Response) => response.json().filter(specificFilter));
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: obj[property] will let you access a property when you don't know is direct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to access object[prop][prop2] given the object and the string "prop.prop2"

from this answer: [Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string) you can do deepFind:

```
function deepFind(obj, path) {
  var paths = path.split('.')
    , current = obj
    , i;

  for (i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
    if (current[paths[i]] == undefined) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      current = current[paths[i]];
    }
  }
  return current;
}
```

then do

```
getFilteredFMsBy(property, value) {
    property = "details.name";
    function specificFilter(obj) {
        return deepFind(obj, property) == value; // <-- use it here
    }
    return this._http.get(this.Url).map((response: Response) => response.json().filter(specificFilter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
getFilteredFMsBy(property: string, value:any) {
    return this._http.get(this.Url).map((response: Response) => response.json().filter((obj) => { return obj[property] == value; }));
}
```