# Clone object and update view

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple service to update an object. I deep clone the initial object and update the clone one.

As you can see, it works well, but the view is not updated. How can I do to update the view on changes ?

Here is the code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eh4cds?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

*And another question, how can I do to modify the value of `number.three` passing the path to function like : "number.three" ? : Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817473/5627096*

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ObjectService } from './object.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private object: any;

  constructor (private objectService: ObjectService) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    this.object = this.objectService.getObject();
  }  

  changeObject () {
    this.objectService.changeObject('two', 'I\'m the one you need')
  }
}
```

**ObjectService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectService {
    public object = {
      one: 'One',
      two: 'Two',
      number: {
        three: 'Three'
      }
    }

    public getObject () {
      return this.object;
    }

    public changeObject (path: string, value: any) {
      console.log('initial', this.object, path, value);
      let clone = { ...this.object, [path]: value };
      console.log('clone', clone);
      return this.object;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
{{ object.one }}
<br>
{{ object.two }}
<br>
{{ object.number.three }}
<br>

<button (click)="changeObject()">Change object</button>
```

Comment: you can use `Object.assign()` to deep clone your object

Comment: Yes I know, but you will get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the returned value inside the **changeObject**

```
  changeObject () {
    this.object =  this.objectService.changeObject('two', 'I\'m the one you need');

  }
```

Also i think you need to return cloned one instead of object

```
   public changeObject (path: string, value: any) {
      console.log('initial', this.object, path, value);
      let clone = { ...this.object, [path]: value };
      console.log('clone', clone);
      return clone;
    }
```

**[STACBKLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eh4cds?file=app%2Fobject.service.ts)**

Comment: Yes, great, it's working. (you forgot to update the stackblitz). And about my second question ?

Comment: That's ok, I've found my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817473/5627096