# How to store a object path

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to store an Object path in to variable. But not works. any one help me please?

here is my try:

```
var object = {"india": { "chennai" : {"sholing":"hi"}}};

var path = ['india']['chennai']['sholing'];

console.log( object.india.chennai ); //works

console.log( object[path] ); //not works
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/wo2027oz/)

Comment: Why? Further describing your use case would be helpful.

Comment: Store an array of strings and use `.reduce()`. You should already know from debugging that your `path` attempt won't be useful.

Comment: You want a [lens](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/an-introduction-into-lenses-in-javascript-e494948d1ea5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array for the keys and a function wich reduces the object by using the keys for the property access.

```js
const getValue = (object, path) => path.reduce((r, k) => (r || {})[k], object);

var object = { india: { chennai: { sholing: "hi" } } },
    path = ['india', 'chennai', 'sholing'];

console.log(object.india.chennai );
console.log(getValue(object, path));
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to reference each property via bracket notation. So, `object[path]` won't work (as @Crazy Train pointed out, your debugging should have shown you that your `var path = ...` throws an error), but if you have an array of paths like `let path = ['india', 'chennai', 'sholing']` then you can use them to access the deep property like `object[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]]`.

You're probably much better off using a utility helper to do this for you, such as Lodash's [toPath](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#toPath) and [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) functions:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

See other answers:

- [Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string)
- [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)