# Javascript update values in nested object by array path

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, nested, traversal

Given the nested object:

```
{
    name: 'UK',
    toggled: false,
    active: false,
    children: [{
            name: 'Region 1',
            active: false,
            toggled: false,
            children: [{
                    name: 'Heathrow T1',
                    toggled: false,
                    active: false,
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'HTT',
                    toggled: false,
                    active: false,
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Region 2',
            active: false,
            toggled: false,
            children: [{
                name: Gatwick North,
                active: false,
                toggled: false,
                children: []
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the given path

```
['UK', 'Region 2', 'Gatwick North']
```

how can I manage to add active/toggled properties to true for the path in the nested object matching the above array.

The output should be the following:

```
{
    name: 'UK',
    toggled: true,
    active: true,
    children: [{
            name: 'Region 1',
            active: false,
            toggled: false,
            children: [{
                    name: 'Heathrow T1',
                    toggled: false,
                    active: false,
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'HTT',
                    toggled: false,
                    active: false,
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Region 2',
            active: true,
            toggled: true,
            children: [{
                name: 'Gatwick North',
                active: true,
                toggled: true,
                children: []
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to implement this with recursion with no success so far. I was searching through questions and none of them matched my current situation.

Comment: Please show what you tried rather than merely writing that you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple example of using recursion, explanations are in code as comments

```js
const obj = {name: 'UK',toggled: false,active: false,children: [{name: 'Region 1',active: false,toggled: false,children: [{name: 'Heathrow T1',toggled: false,active: false,children: []},{name: 'HTT',toggled: false,active: false,children: []},]},{name: 'Region 2',active: false,toggled: false,children: [{name: 'Gatwick North',active: false,toggled: false,children: []}]}]};

const checkAndChange = (obj) => { // function that will check if name exists in array and change toggle and active properties
  const arr = ['UK', 'Region 2', 'Gatwick North'];
  if (arr.includes(obj.name)) {
    obj.toggled = true;
    obj.active = true;
  }
}

const recursion = (obj) => {
   const o = obj;
   checkAndChange(o); // check if name exists in array and change toggle and active properties
   if (o.children.length > 0) { // check if has children
     o.children.forEach(v => { // if has children do the same recursion for every children
       recursion(v);
      });
   }
   return o; // return final new object
}

console.log(recursion(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive method to find the path and update the value.

```js
var obj = [{name: 'UK',toggled: false,active: false,children: [{name: 'Region 1',active: false,toggled: false,children: [{name: 'Heathrow T1',toggled: false,active: false,children: []},{name: 'HTT',toggled: false,active: false,children: []},]},{name: 'Region 2',active: false,toggled: false,children: [{name: 'Gatwick North',active: false,toggled: false,children: []}]}]}];

function FilterArray(temp2,i){
 temp2.filter(function(el){
      if(el['name']==path[i]){
         el['toggled']=true;
          el['active']=true;
        if(i!=path.length-1){
          FilterArray(el['children'],++i);
        }
      }
  });
}

console.log("Before");
console.log(obj);
var path=['UK', 'Region 2', 'Gatwick North'];
FilterArray(obj,0);

console.log("After");
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: your example isn't working, properties are still false

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan I thought only last children toggle should be true. Now edited the code, please check

Comment: The dataset it was supposed to be an object, not an array

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817473/296430) on a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string):

```
function deep_value(obj, path){
    for (var i=0; i<path.length; i++){
        obj = obj[path[i]];
    };
    return obj;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var obj = {
  foo: { bar: 'baz' }
};

alert(deep_value(obj, ['foo','bar'])); // alerts "baz"
```

**Extra**: the same function can also be used for arrays

```
var arr = [
  ['item 0.0', 'item 0.1'],
  ['item 1.0', 'item 1.1'],
  ['item 2.0', 'item 2.1'],
]
console.log(deep_value(arr, [2,1])); // logs "item 2.1"
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/LYYgGxP)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for nested arrays.

parameters:
     - `array`: array to update
     - `path`: what to update (`[0] - array[0], [2,1] - array[2][1], etc.`)
     - `data`: data to assign

```js
    function updateArray(array, path, data) {
        const index = path.shift();
        if (path.length) {
            if (!Array.isArray(array[index])) {
                array[index] = [];
            }
            updateArray(array[index], path, data);
        } else {
            array[index] = data;
        }
    }
```