# How can I update this nested object's value if one of its properties match in JS?

Tags: javascript

I saw many answers, but I haven't been able to modify any to my need.

**Object**

```
{
  "id": "476ky1",
  "custom_id": null,
  "name": "Reunião com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton",
  "text_content": null,
  "description": null,
  "status": {
    "id": "p3203621_11svBhbO"
  },
  "archived": false,
  "creator": {
    "id": 3184709
  },
  "time_spent": 0,
  "custom_fields": [{
    "id": "36c0de9a-9243-4259-ba57-bd590ba07fe0",
    "name": "Comments",
    "value": "dsdsdsds"
  }],
  "attachments": []
}
```

Within `custom_fields`, if the property name's value is `Comments`, update the `value` property.

I've tried it like this, using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69495193), for example, but it doesn't produce the expected result.

```
const updatedComment = [{ name: "Comments", value: "The comment is updated"}];
updateNestedObj(taskData, updatedComment)


function updateNestedObj(obj, updates) {
    const updateToApply = updates.find(upd => upd.id === obj.id);
    if (updateToApply) {
        obj.title = updateToApply.content;
        obj.note = updateToApply.note;
    }
    // Apply updates to any child objects
    for(let k in obj) {
        if (typeof(obj[k]) === 'object') {
            updateNestedObj(obj[k], updates);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `id` property in `updatedComments`.

Comment: In fact, it should update ```value``` if ```name``` is equal to ```Comments```, because there could be new custom fields, but this is the one to be updated. Thanks, @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong property names when you search `updates` for `updateToApply`, and then when assigning the value.

When you recurse on children, you need to distinguish between arrays and ordinary objects, so you can loop over the nested arrays. You also have to skip `null` properties, because `typeof null == 'object'`.

```js
const updatedComment = [{
  name: "Comments",
  value: "The comment is updated"
}];


function updateNestedObj(obj, updates) {
  let updateToApply = updates.find(upd => upd.name == obj.name);
  if (updateToApply) {
    obj.value = updateToApply.value;
  }
  // Apply updates to any child objects
  Object.values(obj).forEach(child => {
    if (Array.isArray(child)) {
      child.forEach(el => updateNestedObj(el, updates));
    } else if (typeof(child) === 'object' && child != null) {
      updateNestedObj(child, updates);
    }
  });
}

const taskData = {
  "id": "476ky1",
  "custom_id": null,
  "name": "Reunião com o novo Gerente de Vendas - Airton",
  "text_content": null,
  "description": null,
  "status": {
    "id": "p3203621_11svBhbO"
  },
  "archived": false,
  "creator": {
    "id": 3184709
  },
  "time_spent": 0,
  "custom_fields": [{
    "id": "36c0de9a-9243-4259-ba57-bd590ba07fe0",
    "name": "Comments",
    "value": "dsdsdsds"
  }],
  "attachments": []
};

updateNestedObj(taskData, updatedComment)
console.log(taskData);
```

Comment: Impressive! So much to learn! Thank you!

Comment: There really shouldn't be any recursion here for this specific question

Comment: Why not? Maybe the field to replace is nested very deeply?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const updatedComment = [{ name: "Comments", value: "A new comment value" }]
// you can add as many updates as you want

function update(obj, updates) {
  for (const update in updates) {
    for (const field in obj.custom_fields) {
      if (obj.obj.custom_fields.name == update.name) {
        obj.obj.custom_fields.value = update.value
      }
    }
  }
}

update(obj, updatedComment)
```

Comment: Thank you! It gives me: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'custom_fields' of undefined```, but it's there... I'm trying to find out why here.

Comment: @onit `obj` should be `taskData` :I