# Filter an object by partial paths

Tags: javascript

How to filter an object given its partial path?

As an example.

```
let address  = {
  country :{
    name:'Japan',
    city:{
      name:'Tokyo',
      town: {
        name:'korushawa'
      }
    },
    code:'JP'
  },
  nearbyCountry:'Korea'
}
```

**path1: *countr.cit***

For `address`, **path1 will result in**

```
{
  country :{
    city:{
      name:'Tokyo',
      town: {
        name:'korushawa'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**path2: countr**

For path2,
I should get entire `address` object because *countr* is present in `country` and `nearbyCountry`

```
{
  country :{
    name:'Japan',
    city:{
      name:'Tokyo',
      town: {
        name:'korushawa'
      }
    }
  },
  nearbyCountry:'Korea'
}
```

Edit: I have been able to solve this when given an exact path (ex: `country.city`). But having difficulty with partial paths.

Comment: Can you add the solution you have for full paths?

Comment: Its actually very straightforward. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817473/10183456)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach rely on filtering the entries and rebuilding a new object by mapping objects with a single property.

```js
function getParts(object, fragments) {
    var [part, ...rest] = fragments.split('.');

    return Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .entries(object)
        .filter(([key]) => key.toLowerCase().includes(part))
        .map(([k, v]) => {
            if (!rest.length) return { [k]: v };
            var parts = v && typeof v === 'object' && getParts(v, rest.join('.'));
            if (parts) return { [k]: parts };
        })
    );
}

let address = { country: { name: 'Japan', city: { name: 'Tokyo', town: { name: 'korushawa' } }, code: 'JP' }, nearbyCountry: 'Korea' };

console.log(getParts(address, 'countr.cit'));
console.log(getParts(address, 'countr'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks. `([key]) => key.toLowerCase().includes(part)` could be `([key]) => key.toLowerCase().includes(part.toLowerCase())`.

Answer (score 4):

- You could create a recursive function which takes an object and an array of partial paths as a parameter.
- Get the latest partial path and `filter` the keys which [`include`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) that path
- If there are no keys, return null
- Else, create an object from the keys using `reduce`

  - if there are no more keys left, just add the all the filtered properties of `obj` to the accumulator
  - else, recursively call the function get another nested object

```js
const address={country:{name:'Japan',city:{name:'Tokyo',town:{name:'korushawa'}},code:'JP'},nearbyCountry:'Korea'};

function filterObject(obj, paths) {
  if (!obj) return null;

  const partial = paths.shift(),
        filteredKeys = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k.toLowerCase().includes(partial));

  if (!filteredKeys.length) return null; // no keys with the path found
  
  return filteredKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    if(!paths.length) return { ...acc, [key]: obj[key] }
    
    const nest = filterObject(obj[key], [...paths]) // filter another level
    return nest ? { ...acc, [key]: nest } : acc
  }, null)
}

let path;
console.log(path = 'countr', ':');
console.log(filterObject(address, path.split('.')))

console.log(path = 'countr.cit', ':');
console.log(filterObject(address, path.split('.')))

console.log(path = 'countr.cit.to', ':');
console.log(filterObject(address, path.split('.')))

console.log(path = 'countr.cit.doesntexist', ':');
console.log(filterObject(address, path.split('.')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you just need the first key that fully or partial matches the keys, you could split the `path` and use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this. If the key is found, return the object, else find the keys which `include` the given key (This gives the data for the last key match. Not the entire object tree)

```js
const address={country:{name:'Japan',city:{name:'Tokyo',town:{name:'korushawa'}},code:'JP'},nearbyCountry:'Korea'},
    path = "countr.cit";

const output = path.split('.').reduce((obj, key) => {
  if (key in obj) {
    return obj[key];
  } else {
    let found = Object.keys(obj).find(k => k.includes(key));
    if (found)
      return obj[found]
    else
      return {}
  }
}, address);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is you can only have one subtree in output at a time. Ex: for path 'country', it will not give  `nearbyCountry:'Korea'` subtree.

Comment: OP said: _"For path2, I should get entire address object because countr is **present in** country and nearbyCountry_. `startsWith` will not work neither `includes()`. You will need a case-insensitive `RegExp`.

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't fully understand your goal (for example: why on your first output example do you keep `name` property of `country` object but not the `code` property), I will give you two approachs that I hope can help you.

## First approach:

In this first approach we recursively traverse the main object to filter out the `keys` that don't match at a particular level. The output will be an `object` with the properties that match at a specific level:

```js
let address = {
  country: {
    name: 'Japan',
    city: {name: 'Tokyo', town: {name: 'korushawa'}},
    code: 'JP'
  },
  nearbyCountry: {name: 'Korea', code: 'KO'}
};

const myFilter = (obj, keys) =>
{
    if (keys.length <= 0)
        return obj;

    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
        (nObj, k) => k.toLowerCase().match(keys[0])
            ? ({...nObj, [k]: myFilter(obj[k], keys.slice(1))})
            : nObj,
        {}
    );
}

const customFilter = (o, k) => myFilter(
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)),
    k.split(".").map(x => x.toLowerCase())
);

console.log("Filter by 'countr':", customFilter(address, "countr"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit.to':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit.to"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit.lala':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit.lala"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

As you can see, when filtering by `"countr.cit"` this approach keeps the `key = nearbyCountry` even if there isn't an inner `key` matching with `cit` inside of it.

## Second approach

In this approach we going to filter out all the `first-level keys` of the main `object` that don't have a match on all the sections of the provided `path`. However, I have to say that this approach is a little strange. I believe this will have more sense if your input is an array of objects, not just one object.

```js
let address = {
  country: {
    name: 'Japan',
    city: {name: 'Tokyo', town: {name: 'korushawa'}},
    code: 'JP'
  },
  nearbyCountry: {name: 'Korea', code: 'KO'}
};

const myFilter = (obj, paths) =>
{
    let newObj = {};

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) =>
    {
        let res = paths.slice(1).reduce((o, cp) => 
        {
            if (o === undefined) return o;
            let found = Object.keys(o).find(k => k.toLowerCase().match(cp));
            return found !== undefined ? o[found] : found;
        }, val);

        if (key.toLowerCase().match(paths[0]) && res !== undefined)
            newObj[key] = val;
    });

    return newObj;
}

const customFilter = (o, k) => myFilter(
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)),
    k.split(".").map(x => x.toLowerCase())
);

console.log("Filter by 'countr':", customFilter(address, "countr"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit.to':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit.to"));
console.log("Filter by 'countr.cit.lala':", customFilter(address, "countr.cit.lala"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Finally, the other thing you may want to do is already shown on the answer provided by **@adiga**.