# Function to replace a substring with a function value in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, evaluation, template-literals

I need a function which will accept test arguments and return a formatted response

```js
format('Hello, {name}!', {name: 'world'}); // Hello, world!

format('Hello, {user.name.first} {user.name.last}!', {user: {name: {first: 'John', last: 'Smith'}}}); // Hello, John Smith!

format('Hello, {user.name.first.f1} {user.name.last}!', {user: {name: {first: {f1:'John'}, last: 'Smith'}}}); // Hello, John Smith!
```

I did this. But is it a good approach ? Basic idea was to convert the string to template. Is there any better approach ?

```js
var format = (str, obj) => {

  str = str.replaceAll('{', '${obj.');
  let newStr = eval('`' + str + '`');
    
  console.log(newStr);
}
```

Comment: What parts are you struggling with? [What have you tried](https://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Please edit your post with more details about your previous attempts so that we can help you.

Comment: Updated the post with the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method accepts a function as a second parameter, the parameter is the matched substring. You can use regex to match `{abc.def.ghi}` and with the function return the value at this path.

The `accessByPath` function is based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string).

```js
const accessByPath = (obj, path) => {
    const parts = path.split('.')
    // TODO: Properly handle invalid path
    for (let i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
        obj = obj[parts[i]];
    };
    return obj;
};

const format = (str, obj) => {
  return str.replaceAll(/{[^}]+}/g, substring => accessByPath(obj, substring.slice(1, -1)))
}

console.log(format('Hello, {name}!', {name: 'world'}))
console.log(format('Hello, {user.name.first} {user.name.last}!', {user: {name: {first: 'John', last: 'Smith'}}}))
console.log(format('Hello, {user.name.first.f1} {user.name.last}!', {user: {name: {first: {f1:'John'}, last: 'Smith'}}}))
```

As you asked whether yours is a good approach: Using eval in many cases introduces security risks (e.g. in your case if a user somehow can control the `str` value, they can execute any javascript on your page).

Answer (score 0):

> *I did this. But is it a good approach ?*

I can not really tell, but ... ***Consider this ...***

```js
var format = (str, obj) => {

  str = str.replaceAll('{', '${obj.');
  console.log(str);

  let newStr = eval('`' + str + '`');
  console.log(newStr);
}
format('{alert("Think before \\"eval\\"uating!")}', window);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Read on SO about why eval has limited use cases ... [why is eval evil](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+why+is+eval+evil)

**Edit**

For a custom template-string evaluation / interpolation I would stick to the syntax of JavaScript [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of cause without enclosing the template string by backticks.

For the substitution one needs a regex which targets both the valid substitute template syntax `${ foo.bar }` and a valid object path syntax. Thus variable/property names can start with `$`, `_` and upper/lowercase latin letters only, whereas within a variable name the numbers from `0` to `9` are allowed. Thus a regex which does [capture](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) such a [valid object path from a valid template syntax](https://regex101.com/r/OtNiAB/1/) looks like this ...

```
/\$\{\s*(?<path>[a-zA-Z_$]\w*(?:\.[a-zA-Z_$]\w*)*)\s*\}/g
```

Value interpolation then is not that complicated anymore. One just does [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) an object path like `'foo.bar.baz'` into an array of property names like `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. The final value can be evaluated via a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which programmatically walks down the property chain of the provided object/type ...

```js
function evaluateCustomTemplate(template, type) {
  function evaluateValue(value, key) {
    return value && value[key];
  }
  function interpolateValue(match, path) {
    return path
      .split(/\./)
      .reduce(evaluateValue, type);
  }
  const regXValidObjectPath =
    // [https://regex101.com/r/OtNiAB/1/]
    (/\$\{\s*(?<path>[a-zA-Z_$]\w*(?:\.[a-zA-Z_$]\w*)*)\s*\}/g);

  return template.replace(regXValidObjectPath, interpolateValue); 
}

console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hi, ${ alert("Think before \\"eval\\"uating!") }!',
    window
  )
);

console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ name }!',
    { name: 'world' }
  )
);
console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ user.name.first } ${ user.name.last }!',
    { user: { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Smith' } } }
  )
);
console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ user.name.first.f1 } ${ user.name.last }!',
    { user: { name: { first: { f1:'John' }, last: 'Smith' } } }
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above approach based on a less rigid object-path regex like ... [`/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/OtNiAB/2/) ... then turns into the one beneath ...

```js
function evaluateCustomTemplate(template, type) {
  function interpolateValue(match, path) {
    return path
      .trim() // minimum whitespace sanitation.
      .split(/\./)
      .reduce((value, key) => value && value[key], type);
  }
  // [https://regex101.com/r/OtNiAB/2/]
  const regXDirtyObjectPath = (/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g);

  return template.replace(regXDirtyObjectPath, interpolateValue); 
}

console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hi, ${ alert("Think before \\"eval\\"uating!") }!',
    window
  )
);

console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ name }!',
    { name: 'world' }
  )
);
console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ user.name.first } ${ user.name.last }!',
    { user: { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Smith' } } }
  )
);
console.log(
  evaluateCustomTemplate(
    'Hello, ${ user.name.first.f1 } ${ user.name.last }!',
    { user: { name: { first: { f1:'John' }, last: 'Smith' } } }
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```