# Extract data from object based on key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to find the property value of an object based on key. I have below function `getData` which returns the data based on `key` passed as input parameter.

```
const getData = (key) => {
  let row = {isSelected: true, Data: {Id: '1A', Value: 'LD'}};
  return row[key];
}
console.log(getData('Data'));
```

In normal scenario it is working fine but how can I get the property value from nested object `Data.Value`.

If I call getData function as `getData('Data.Value')`, It should return `LD`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: @pilchard, I had a look on the answer but don't find the solution for my problem.

Comment: Every answer is a solution to your problem, you need to parse the string and then iteratively or recursively access the object. Another duplicate would be [Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string)

Comment: @pilchard, my bad. there were too many tabs open and I looked at wrong tab. It has the answer on url suggested by you. However I would prefer short and simple solution by Ori.

Comment: The lodash solution is also included in the duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303609/13762301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `_.get()` function that returns the value at a path:

```js
const getData = path => {
  const row = {isSelected: true, Data: {Id: '1A', Value: 'LD', InnerData: {Id: 1, Value: "Something"}}};
    
  return _.get(row, path);
}

console.log(getData('Data'));
console.log(getData('Data.Value'));
console.log(getData('Data.InnerData.Value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Second answer in the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303609/13762301

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest accessing the nested value like this:

```js
getData("Data").Value
```

Comment: I can't hardcode the .Value. It may have multilevel nested object and property names are dynamic.

Comment: You could access it like this too for one level of nesting: `getData("Data")[someVar]`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. It is not matter how deep is your row. Try this. It would be multilevel nested object too. For example

> Data.InnerData.Value...

```js
const getData = (key) =>{
    let row = {isSelected: true, Data: {Id: '1A', Value: 'LD', InnerData: {Id: 1, Value: "Something"}}};
    var keys = key.split('.');
    var res = row;
    for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++){
        res = res[keys[i]];
    }
    
    return res;
}

console.log(getData('Data.InnerData.Value'));
```

Comment: He said that he can't hardcode the key to get the data.

Comment: if it is dynamic send dynamic key to getData(). For example get keys from database and send it to getData()

Answer (score 0):

When you have dynamic object keys you can use javascript Object.keys method.

```
var data = getData("Data")
var dynamicKeys = Object.keys(data)

for(int i=0; i < dynamicKeys.length; i++){
   console.log(data[dynamicKeys[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your object goes two level at most, you can try this simple solution

```
const isObject = (value) => {
   return typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value) && value !== null;
};

const testData = { isSelected: true, data: { id: '1A', value: 'LD' } };

const getData = (key) => {
   const keys = key.split('.');
   if (isObject(testData[keys[0]])) {
      return testData[keys[0]][keys[1]];
   }
   return testData[keys[0]];
};

console.log(getData('data.id'));
```